# Multiple cart fields/notes

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

First time using Commerce and made pretty good progress, but... I need to collect a few bits of information at the **cart** stage. The site is selling conference tickets, and I need to know:

1. if the delegate has any dietary requirements
2. whether or not they have been asked to speak
3. and if they have, to provide a short bio

I'm aware of the `{{ item.note }}` tag, which I'm using for the dietary requirements. But how can I capture the other two fields?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What version of Commerce do you use? I guess you could create Order fields and fill them by posting to update-cart with a field name of `fields[your-field-handle]`?

Comment: Hi Paul. I'm using Commerce 2. Unfamiliar with order fields so I'll have a look at that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's suggestion of using order fields worked perfectly.